# when i connect the data base, it is showing in Data source is error(RED LINE)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

RED LINE Shows Represents text as a series of Unicode characters (LOOK DATA SOURCE)
Please give some ideas to solve this

Comment: Prefix the string with `@"Your connection\string\here"` or use double slashes `\\\`. It doesn't understand the escape sequence.

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer